# MySql query taking long time to execute when called from VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve some data from MySql database using Excel Vba. Everything is working fine...but the MySql query is taking too much time to execute.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
  d.DATE,
  c.name,
  c.address,
  c.state_name,
  c.contact_no,
  d.AMOUNT,
  d.BY_NAME,
  d.NARATION,
  t.REMARK
FROM
  database1.data d
JOIN
  (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    cust_id,
    OR_NO
  FROM
    database1.ordbill
) o ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(database1.d.NARATION,
':',
-1) = o.OR_NO
JOIN
  database1.contact c ON o.cust_id = c.id
JOIN
  database1.total t ON t.VCH_NO = d.VCH_NO
WHERE
  d.PARTY_NAME = 'advance' AND(
    d.`BY_NAME` = 'Bank1' OR d.`BY_NAME` = 'CASH' OR d.`BY_NAME` = 'Bank2'
  ) AND d.DATE BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2019-09-30'
ORDER BY
  d.DATE ASC `
```

Comment: too much time - this is a relative concept, not absolute! How long does the query take to run? How many records are there in the tables? What indexes are there in the tables? What does explain say?

Comment: it taking approx 30 minute to execute. There are 21000 records in one table.

Comment: Does it take a long time running in mysql..if not suspect network traffic or excel.

Comment: Yes it take a long time running in mysql..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already index  on  table contact pk id an index

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM `loans` 
    WHERE `date` >= '2019-11-25' 
      AND `date`<='2019-11-28' 
    AND `designation` LIKE '%sdf%'
why does this happen ?

SELECT d.DATE
  ,c.name
  ,c.address
  ,c.state_name
  ,c.contact_no
  , d.AMOUNT
  , d.BY_NAME
  , d.NARATION
  ,t.REMARK 
  FROM database1.data d JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT cust_id, OR_NO FROM database1.ordbill
  ) o ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(database1.d.NARATION,':',-1)=o.OR_NO 
  JOIN database1.contact c on o.cust_id=c.id 
  JOIN database1.total t on t.VCH_NO=d.VCH_NO 
  WHERE d.PARTY_NAME = 'advance' 
  AND (d.`BY_NAME` = 'Bank1' OR d.`BY_NAME` = 'CASH' OR d.`BY_NAME` = 'Bank2')  
  AND d.DATE BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2019-09-30' 
  ORDER BY d.DATE ASC
```

be sure you have also proper  composite  index  on

```
table  data columns(PARTY_NAME, BY_NAME, DATE, VCH_NO )
```

and a index  also

```
table total  column (VCH_NO)
```

Comment: sorry , i can't understand what are you trying to say. I am a beginner in coding. The above coding doing what i want but taking too much time to execute.

Comment: be sure you have in the tables suggest  .. the  composite index  ..  (index  which involve more than a columns) as described  in answer ..  ..asnwer  updated..  hope is more clear